# Transforming XML to JSON in Wso2

Tags: json, xml, transformation, wso2-esb

I am Trying to Transform XML payload to JSON format using WSO2 Proxy service.As part of this I did the following.But I couldn't recieve the JSON Format response.Could any one help me on this.

I have removed comment from the following message builder and formatter from axis2.xml and axis2_blocking_client.xml in location `wso2esb-4.9.0\repository\conf\axis2`

```
messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"

messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"
```

ANd My Proxy is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="TestXML_To_JSON"
   transports="http,https"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">

   <target>

  <inSequence>
     <header name="To" action="remove"/>
     <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
     <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <person>
              <fullName>
                 <firstName>Laks</firstName>
                 <lastName>M</lastName>
              </fullName>
              <birthDate>
                 <month>May</month>
                 <date>31</date>
                 <year>2015</year>
              </birthDate>
              <address>
                 <street>test1</street>
                 <province>test2</province>
                 <city>Colombo</city>
                 <country>test3</country>
                 <postalCode>0002</postalCode>
              </address>
           </person>
        </format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <property name="messageType"
               value="application/json"
               scope="axis2"
               type="STRING"/>
     <send/>
  </inSequence>
```

I am expecting the response in JSON Format as key value pairs as I set the property messageType as application/json.But when I test this Proxy, it gives the output as follows...... JSONObject

```
             <jsonObject>
               <person>
              <fullName>
                 <firstName>Laks</firstName>
                 <lastName>M</lastName>
              </fullName>
              <birthDate>
                 <month>May</month>
                 <date>31</date>
                 <year>2015</year>
              </birthDate>
              <address>
                 <street>test1</street>
                 <province>test2</province>
                 <city>Colombo</city>
                 <country>test3</country>
                 <postalCode>0002</postalCode>
              </address>
           </person>
           </jsonObject>
```

Please help me how to configure my proxy or message builder and formatters to get the response as actual JSON format as Key valuye pairs.

Thanks,
Lakshmi

Answer (score 0):

I went through your configurations and seems it works correctly.
Following are the steps followed.

1) Checked weather following  formatter is enabled in axis2.xml.

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

2) Enable the wire logs by uncommenting the following line in log4j.properties file available in repository/conf folder.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

3) following is the sample proxy configuration i used, which is similar to yours but I included address endpoint to send the message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestXML_To_JSON"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <person>
                  <fullName>
                     <firstName>Laks</firstName>
                     <lastName>M</lastName>
                  </fullName>
                  <birthDate>
                     <month>May</month>
                     <date>31</date>
                     <year>2015</year>
                  </birthDate>
                  <address>
                     <street>test1</street>
                     <province>test2</province>
                     <city>Colombo</city>
                     <country>test3</country>
                     <postalCode>0002</postalCode>
                  </address>
               </person>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

4) invoked proxy service using SoapUI
5) following logs visibled which show that message is going out as json.

```
[2016-01-05 16:38:30,351] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-01-05 16:38:30,352] DEBUG - wire << "d4[\r][\n]"
[2016-01-05 16:38:30,352] DEBUG - wire << "{"person":{"fullName":{"firstName":"Laks","lastName":"M"},"birthDate":{"month":"May","date":31,"year":2015},"address":{"street":"test1","province":"test2","city":"Colombo","country":"test3","postalCode":"0002"}}}[\r][\n]"
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable application/json formatter in repository/conf/axis2 file as below

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
```

Then add the following property to your syanpse config (proxy,api)

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
```